# Django - accessing a stored excel file in Django model viewer

Tags: python, django, excel

I am trying to access excel files through the django-admin model viewing portal.

Each excel file is generated through a seperate algorithm, and is already in a directory called **excel_stored**

each excel file is generated with an ID that corresponds to its model # in django. So it would be excel_%ID%.xlsx or excel_23.xlsx for example.

I want my django FileField() to access the relevant excel file so that I can download it from my django admin portal, just like I can access my other model information (city name, time uploaded, etc).

**Here is a pseudo-code of what I'd want to do:**

**My models.py would look like this**

```
excel = models.FileField()
```

**The process of saving would look like this**

```
create_excel()

### EXCEL WAS SAVED TO DIR: excel_stored ###

save_excel = Model(excel = file.directory((os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'lead/excel_stored/excel_%s.xlsx' %ID))
save_excel.save()
```

Id then be able to download it like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HRUU.gif

I know there's a lot I'm missing, but most documentation I find refers to *uploading* an excel file through forms, not accessing it.

I've been stuck on this for a while, so I'd appreciate some direction! Thank you!

Comment: hi, `xlrd` is a python package useful when working with excel files. you need python to read the data bring it to django part then render it as desired.